# Alternate of Spring HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was using Spring 4.2.x HandlerMethodSelector class - now migrating to Spring 5.1.x. Can anyone please help? how can we replace the below code in the latest Spring version?

```
final Set<Method> methods = HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(userType, new MethodFilter()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Method method)
        {
            return hasRequestMappingOverrideAnnotation(method);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Getting error org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector..

While using Spring 5.1.6

Comment: I suggested using `MethodIntrospector`

Comment: Yes that I am using

Answer (score 1):

[HandlerMethodSelector](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector.java) replaced with [MethodIntrospector](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/MethodIntrospector.html)

> @deprecated as of Spring 4.2.3, in favor of the generalized and refined {@link MethodIntrospector}

You have similar method to use

```
 static Set<Method> selectMethods(Class<?> targetType, ReflectionUtils.MethodFilter methodFilter)
```

> Select methods on the given target type based on a filter.

Comment: Getting error org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.. While using Spring 5.1.6