# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using Spring 5.1.6,  changed the code accordingly [Alternate of Spring HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305290/alternate-of-spring-handlermethodselector-selectmethods?noredirect=1#comment104904183_59305290)

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethodSelector

Comment: Those errors generally come from the fact you are mixing jars/modules from different versions of a framework (in this case Spring). Check your classpath, all the Spring versions should match.

Comment: Yes found, it worked.